# Connectivity Checking notation is concerning

Tags: 22.04, security, privacy

Under Settings → *Privacy* → *Connectivity*, I found Ubuntu provides a short notation, the second half of which concerns me (highlighting my own):

> Connectivity checking is used to detect connection issues and helps you to stay online. **If your network communications are being monitored, it could be used to gather technical information about this computer.**

What exactly does that second half mean by *"being monitored"* and *"gather technical information"*?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the most basic level...if someone - your ISP, your VPN, someone snooping through your Wi-Fi network, a government agency, etc. - is watching to see what servers you connect to, the fact that it checks an Ubuntu address means that the snoop could, at minimum, figure out that you're running Ubuntu, and presumably infer something about how you connect to the internet?

Comment: What are you basing this info on? References please.

Comment: References for what part? What the NetworkManager connectivity check does?

https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html

What URL Ubuntu has set up for connectivity checks?

https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/connectivity-check

The rest seems like just kind of basic logic, I think?